# STM32: How do I place a large buffer into a specific memory region?

Tags: stm32, c, arm, gcc

This is an embedded project using the STM32H7A3ZIT.

I'm trying to store a large LCD image buffer in ram, but my program will not compile, even though the buffer should fit.

I'm using STM32cubeIDE with a GCC compiler.

I declare the buffer in global scope like this:

```
uint16_t lcd_buffer[800*600];
```

This results in the error:

```
... STM32CubeMX Configuration.elf section `.bss' will not fit in region `RAM'
... region `RAM' overflowed by 832768 bytes
```

Checking the linker script, I see that the RAM region is actually rather small.

```
/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
    RAM_EXEC (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x24000000, LENGTH = 1024K
    RAM  (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
    AHB_SRAM (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 128K
}
```

It looks like I need to place the buffer in RAM_EXEC instead, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I tried changing the declaration to:

```
uint16_t lcd_buffer[800*600] __attribute__ ((section (".my_data")));
```

and adding this code to the linker script:

```
.my_data :
{
    KEEP(*(.my_data))
} >RAM_EXEC
```

But that didn't seem to have any effect. The RAM still overflows.

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to store this buffer?

Comment: This is a software question. Maybe you will get a better answer on SO.

Comment: @Mike This is fairly specific to embedded systems, but I'll try there if I don't get a good answer here.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have more RAM available. 2*800*600=960k. Even if that doesn't blow _all_ of your RAM, other parts of your program and the stack will want some RAM too. You can't conjure more physical memory with software.

Comment: When you move your framebuffer into the RAM_EXEC section, do you still get *exactly the same* error, or is it different in some way? If your .bss is still in RAM and your .my_data is in EXEC_RAM, then they should fit...

Comment: The error is *exactly* the same as far as I can tell. I think it's not actually being placed in the RAM_EXEC section.

Comment: 128K is pretty massive for an mcu in general.  Not small.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. My project (created with a wizard) had 2 linker scripts in it:

[image: project files screenshot]

I was assuming that both of them would be used when linking the build, but I believe that in reality only one is used at a time. I think one is intended to be used when executing code from ram, and the other for executing from flash.

I checked, and the FLASH linker script was the only one referenced in the project settings. I was editing the RAM script.

After making my changes to the FLASH script, the program now compiles.

Answer (score 0):

`uint16_t lcd_buffer[800*600] __attribute__((section(".ram_exec")));`

```
MEMORY
{
    RAM_EXEC (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x24000000, LENGTH = 1024K
    RAM  (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
    AHB_SRAM (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 128K
}
```

The second part in your linker will probably look like this, check it.

```
.ram_exec:
{
  . = ALIGN(4);
  *(.ram_exec)
  *(.ram_exec*)
} >RAM_EXEC AT> FLASH
```

*The `AT> FLASH` is only required if you want to initialize the objects in this region.*

The GCC linker is very primitive. It won't shuffle around anything to make it fit. If you want to fit 960k into 1024k it must find one continous block of 960k. If your *(.data) are also placed into RAM_EXEC linking will probably fail.

Comment: I changed my declaration and the entry in the linker script to match your answer, but I still get the error "section '.ram_exec' will not fit in region 'RAM'", so I think something is wrong with my syntax. I even copied and pasted a second time to ensure there is no typo. I must be missing something..

Comment: Can you share the entire linker file, on github gists perhaps?