# Write EEPROM while flashing firmware in MCU

Tags: stm32, arm, eeprom, flash-memories

am using a STM32L0x2 device, Arm Cortex M0 core.

My goal it's to flash a default value in a EEPROM page during the firmware's flash.

Long story short: I want that when flashing the .elf in the MCU (I am using STM32CubeProgrammer) a specific EEPROM's page it's written with the data i want.

My boss said there should be a specific #pragma but i wans't able to find anything on the manual.

Thanks.

Comment: Impossible to say how to do it because you are not telling which toolchain (i.e. compiler) you use. Chanses are it's not even done with #pragma in your compiler since you did not find it.

Comment: i tought that the toolchain was implicit.

anyway: STM32CubeIDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Easy method, very portable.
   Store the defaults in a normal const structure, on bootup check if the eeprom is written, if not, write it. By default the memory will read `FF`, so a blank check is easy.
   *Drawback: extra code.*
   *Advantage: you can keep contents during firmware update, if you want to.*
2. Toolchain method, highly integrated.
   Change the linker file to give the EERPOM it's own section.
   Put a const structure in a file called `eeprom.c`, at put `eeprom.o` in this new section.
   *Drawback: keeping contents on firmware upgrade is difficult.

   Advantage: you learn about linker files.*

There is no pragma to use, ST's are not AVR's.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'll investigate both solution but i really like 2)

Comment: @DaniloAgosto There is an example posted somewhere here. I can't find it, maybe on StackOverflow...

Comment: @DaniloAgosto You can use this to get started I guess. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/572629/stm32-how-do-i-place-a-large-buffer-into-a-specific-memory-region/572638#572638